# Maven lost checkstyle config

Tags: maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I try to connect custom `checkstyle.xml` config instead standart `sun_checks.xml` to [this project](https://github.com/triodjangopiter/bridge/blob/master/pom.xml).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>src/main/resources/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
    </configuration>
    <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
            <reports>
                <report>checkstyle</report>
            </reports>
        </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

But `mvn -B clean verify checkstyle:checkstyle` get output with `sun_checks.xml`

```
[INFO] There are 206 errors reported by Checkstyle 8.29 with sun_checks.xml ruleset.
```

Why `<configLocation>` is ignored, and hiw to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is starting maven task with the config location argument:

```
mvn checkstyle:check -Dcheckstyle.config.location=checkstyle.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello @Pavel try to use checkstyle.xml outside your source code, and optionally set the goal also. It should solve your problem.

```
<properties>
    <checkstyle.configLocation>src/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml</checkstyle.configLocation>
    <checkstyle.suppressionsLocation>src/checkstyle/suppressions.xml</checkstyle.suppressionsLocation>
</properties>
```

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
<!-- for java
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>8.26</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
-->
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>${checkstyle.configLocation}</configLocation>
                    <suppressionsLocation>${checkstyle.suppressionsLocation}</suppressionsLocation>
                    <sourceDirectories>
                        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                        <sourceDirectory>src/test/java</sourceDirectory>
                    </sourceDirectories>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: perhaps I'm doing somthing wrong but it take the same result. Log https://github.com/triodjangopiter/bridge/runs/1341162926?check_suite_focus=true